# Offset error on bootstrap table when bootstrap-table close and window resizing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I used the bootstrap table in my project, When the bootstrap table is closed with this script :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".removetable").click(function (e) { 
          $(".table-aria").remove();
     });
 });
```

The following error appears when resizing :

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offset')***

Although this error does not cause a problem in the project process, but I want to understand the cause and solve the problem.

you can also see my code in https://github.com/yarandish/OffsetError

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own cache management system.
Use this mechanism https://github.com/Master2V/FormCallSolution.git and it will be solved.